# Javascript Running Total Keeps Adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, cumulative-sum

Yesterday I got great help resolving a $NaN issue so hoping I can get another answer in my code from yesterday, subtotal is adding the totals at the end of each line now and showing a value so that is good, however anytime I enter an amount sold and then go and change that value it adds again, so if I set quantity to 2 and its $50 per, the total for the line item is $100 and the subtotal reflects, but if I change the quantity to 1 the line item becomes $50 correctly, but the subtotal re-adds and becomes $150, I'm not savvy enough with JS to see what I'm doing wrong...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var subtotal = 0;
var stantot = 0;
var showtot = 0;
$("input").keyup(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
        var unitp = parseFloat($("#unitp" + i).val()) || 0;
        var casep = parseFloat($("#casep" + i).val()) || 0;
        var units = parseFloat($("#units" + i).val()) || 0;
        var cases = parseFloat($("#cases" + i).val()) || 0;
        var st_disc = parseFloat($("#st_disc").val()) || 0;
        var sh_disc = parseFloat($("#sh_disc").val()) || 0;

        var unitr = (unitp * units);
        var caser = (casep * cases);
        var result = (unitr + caser);
        var st_disc_fix = (st_disc / 100);
        var sh_disc_fix = (sh_disc / 100);
        var st_disc_solo = (st_disc_fix * result);
        var sh_disc_solo = (sh_disc_fix * result);
        var disc_total = (st_disc_fix + sh_disc_fix);
        var disc_whole = (disc_total * result);

        var disc = (result - disc_whole);
        var st_disc_tot = (result - disc_whole);
        var sh_disc_tot = (result - disc_whole);

        $("#line" + i).val(result.toFixed(2));
        $("#disc" + i).val(disc.toFixed(2));
        subtotal += parseFloat((unitp * units) + (casep * cases));
        stantot += parseFloat(st_disc_tot);
        showtot += parseFloat(sh_disc_tot);
    }
    $("#totretail").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    $("#standiscount").val(stantot.toFixed(2));
    $("#showdiscount").val(showtot.toFixed(2));

    var totship = ($("#totship").val() * 1);
    var tottax = ($("#tottax").val() * 1);

    var finaltotal = (subtotal + stantot + showtot + totship + tottax);
    $("#total").val(finaltotal.toFixed(2));

    });
});
```

Comment: For clarity, each line item comes in individual units and in cases, so there is a case and unit price, and quantities for both, for each line item...

Comment: how come your aren't using unitr and caser when calculating the subtotal?

Comment: On a side note: I woulda thunk "parseFloat($("#sh_disc").val()) || 0" would result in a boolean value, but is does not. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: Ah I was trying to determine whether just passing subtotal += result, or subtotal += (unitr + caser); was messing something up so I broke it down and that didn't fix it and I just havn't changed it back yet

Comment: okay, it wouldn't change anything, but since you already had the variable for it i figured it'd just make it look simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `var subtotal = 0;` inside the `input` listener, so your subtotal is recalculated each time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").keyup(function() {
    var subtotal = 0;
    var stantot = 0;
    var showtot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
```

..

otherwise total will keep growing, the reason `stantot` and `showtot` are working is because they are set from a var with `=` not `+=`.

I moved the other vars in there also, just because it's better.

Comment: he moved the setting of things to zero into the keyup function so that it resets the total every time

Comment: you need to move `var subtotal = 0` inside the `input` listener

Answer (score 1):

What your problem is, is that you never reset subtotal.  It will just keep adding to the previous subtotal every time.  What you need to do is reset it somewhere back to zero before it recalculates

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with these lines:

```
var totship = ($("#totship").val() * 1);
var tottax = ($("#tottax").val() * 1);
```

The `.val()` method in jQuery has a tendency to return Strings. But if you multiply a String by a Number, you get `NaN`. You should force the values to be numbers. This seems to be what you're trying to do with `* 1`, but that's not going to work. Give this a try instead:

```
var totship = +$("#totship").val();
var tottax = +$("#tottax").val();
```

Or if clarity is your thing, you can do:

```
var totship = Number($("#totship").val());
var tottax = Number($("#tottax").val());
```

Or

```
var totship = parseInt($("#totship").val(), 10);
var tottax = parseInt($("#tottax").val(), 10);
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Actually these two fields get added later on to the subtotal, right now I'm just focusing on getting the subtotal to show the right number, these variables didn't really even need to be included in my example but I wanted to include my entire function

Comment: Oh, excuse me, I see now. I'll add another answer regarding your actual issue.